# can SharePoint hosted apps use the office graph?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, office-graph

Can `SharePoint-Hosted` apps use the Microsoft graph rest API? I need to be able to get members of azure ad groups from my SharePoint hosted app.

I read the article at [Authorizing Office 365 SharePoint Apps to read Azure AD data](http://www.sharepoint.bg/Radi/post/Authorizing-Office-365-SharePoint-Apps-to-read-Azure-AD-data.aspx), but it doesn't seem that I can assign a client id to a SharePoint hosted app. are there any known workarounds?

my app is at https://github.com/russgove/SPSecurity

Any advice would be appreciated